# WinForms form shows on constructor before calling .Show()

Tags: vb.net, winforms, activex

Working on old application ported from VB6 to VB.NET.
Applications is using ActiveX controls (Can't replace them).

**Problem is:**
This is MDI application. We are talking about child forms.
When constructor is called to create form it automatically shows that form (in freezed state, because data is loading).

What can cause form to Show in constructor?

There is no call to .Show() method. Visible property is not being set anywhere?

My current workaround is to call Hide() and Applicaiton.DoEvents() after calling contructor to form. But this still flickers form and is ugly code practise.

**UPDATE:**

I determined that in designer generated file at the end of form initializaion, call to this function displays form.

```
CType(Me.someActiveXControll, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
```

This call is needed as there is exception if it gets omitted. I can't replace ActiveX control.

Comment: It is unclear what the problem might be. You should show us relevant parts of your code. Even before seeing the code here you have some advices: not sure why you cannot replace ActiveX controls (actually it seems a quite good idea). The fact that the form is being shown (for an unclear reason) doesn't imply that it should get frozen; the way to avoid that is relying on multi-threading (just 2 threads; `Backgroundworker` would be more than enough). Better don't use `Application.DoEvents()`.

Comment: OK. But you have to share some relevant code (e.g., code where the forms are defined and instantiated), otherwise it would be very difficult to help you. PS: if you are not allowed to use the new .NET functionalities (e.g., controls or multi-threading), you shouldn't waste time by converting the code to .NET at all (it would certainly provoke lots of problems and the resulting application might even be worse than before).

Comment: @varocarbas It does not depend on me. My task is to "fix" it. I have no say in this matter.

Form is created in "normal" way. 
NotNiceForm = new NotNiceForm() //And this shows the form...

Comment: Maybe you can call `Hide()` before the call to `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: @FarhanAnam Call to `Hide()` before call to `InitializeComponent()` does nothing. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Without seeing the whole code it's difficult to provide anything constructive, but have you looked into SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout.

Comment: (IMHO if your work is correcting something and your conclusion is that the correction is worse than letting things like they were before, you should share this knowledge; but completely up to you) Rather than trying to close what is poping up, don't you think that it might be better to avoid it appearing at all? Can you please share all the code defining `NotNiceForm`?

Comment: @varocarbas I know you want to help. But I pasted the exact line that is causing problem and I told how this form is created (simple new()).
And yes. My whole post is about trying to prevent it from appearing in the first place.

Comment: Sorry to say but this line doesn't seem to provoke the form to be shown. The fact of creating a form doesn't make it to be shown and, consequently, there should be something in the definition of your form (in its code) which can explain such a behaviour (= we need to see the code). In any case, I have already spent here too much time. Follow my advice or don't do it, again completely up to you.

Comment: Is the rest of the ctor executing (ie the Sub new code after Initializecompoenent)? If an exception is encountered during form creation it usually isnt reported and NET skips any code after the exception and just shows the form. Some of the description sounds very much like that. You could set a boolean or write to debug as the last line of the ctor and see if that code executes (or breaks at it). You might try to get the powers to be to consider replacing the control with one you write in NET

Comment: @Plutonix That is possible. I don't have access to dev machine now but it will be the first thing to try tomorow. I'll let you know.
P.S. Is there any way to check this exception?

Comment: Any other EndInits in the designer wont run either which might be a big problem.  I was thinking that it would be a way to declare at least that control as UNFIT for use in NET   ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with MDI forms, so these suggestions might be entirely useless, but I'll give it a go.

- Try setting the "Visible" property of the child form to false (Or set it during Load())
- Check the Load() Method, as the Show() is commonly executed after Load(), so if you don't actually need the form until later, don't create it until you DO need it.

Comment: An answer starting with "I've never worked" and/or "suggestions might be entirely useless" doesn't sound as a too good idea. You should better ask questions via comments until being completely sure about what is needed here (by assuming that you have the required knowledge; otherwise, you shouldn't get involved at all. For what? To provoke more doubts and problems? Have you heard about this thing of extinguishing fire with gasoline?).

Comment: Nope. It is to late in Load. Form still flickers (shows for half a second).

Comment: I said I've never worked with MDI forms but still answered because as far as I know, they work similarly to standard winforms Forms.

Comment: I just thought, was it the load method for the child form or the main form when it's too late. Depending how your designer.vb is laid out, it could make a difference. Of course setting it in designer is a better option though because then it shouldn't flicker at all.